# What is the proper syntax to bind a typedef type using pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, syntax, pybind11

I have a struct very similar to this:

```
struct data_point
{
    data_point() = delete;
    data_point(const int& data) :
            m_data(data)
    {}

    int m_data;
};
```

I also have this type declared as such.

```
typedef std::vector<data_point> data_list;
```

The binding for this struct is defined:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(data_lib, ref)
{
    py::class_<data_point> dp(ref, "data_point");
    dp.def(py::init<const int&>());
    dp.def_readwrite("m_data", &data_point::m_data);
}
```

How do I define a binding for the typedef list type? 
Its not clear to me how to do this in the pybind documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific issue, pybind will automatically interpret an std::vector type as a python list when you include `"pybind11/stl.h"` . Thus, a binding for this type is unnecessary.

Ex:

```
#include "pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/stl.h"

struct data_point
{
    data_point() = delete;
    data_point(const int& data) :
            m_data(data)
    {}
    int m_data;
};

std::vector<data_point> make_vec(){
    return {data_point(20), data_point(18)};
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(data_lib, ref)
{
    py::class_<data_point> dp(ref, "data_point");
    dp.def(py::init<const int&>());
    dp.def_readwrite("m_data", &data_point::m_data);

    ref.def("make_vec", &make_vec, "A function that returns a vector of data_points");
}
```

In python, when you import the `data_lib` library you will be able to use functions that return lists of `data_point`.

```
import data_lib
p = data_lib.make_vec()
print len(p)
```

output: `2`

Answer (score 0):

Your `typdef` do not need a specific care to be able to bound by `pybind11`. it can be directly detected by `pybind11` stl features. Example:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MapOfString;

std::string processTypeDef(const MapOfString & key_val);
MapOfString returnTypeDef();
```

Now for binding, you should have:

```
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h> 
#include <pybind11/stl.h> 

py_module.def("setTypeDef", &EX::setTypeDef, ""); // process a typedef
py_module.def("getTypeDef", &EX::getTypeDef, ""); // returns a typedef
```

Now for using:

```
my_map = {"1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3" }
self.assertEqual(setTypeDef(my_map), "112233")

ret_typedef = getTypeDef();
self.assertEqual(len(ret_typedef), 3)
self.assertEqual(ret_typedef["1"], "1")
self.assertEqual(ret_typedef["2"], "2")
self.assertEqual(ret_typedef["3"], "3")
```